# SQL Server Making insert select where not exists atomic

Tags: sql-server

I am aware that `INSERT ... SELECT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT...)` is not atomic.

There is a race condition where two sessions running concurrently can run the select; both see the row does not exist and then both would attempt the insert.

How would you make this statement atomic in SQL Server?  I am not sure which locking hint to use or where to put it.

Comment: Put it in a transaction?

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx